# my code throws out a TypeError i just can't figure out

Tags: python-3.x

So, I've been working on a python implementation of wheel of fortune and every time I test my code it works fine but after a while of testing it throws out an error. Here's the code:

```
from random import choice
def spin_the_wheel():
    wheel = ["BANKRUPT", 650, "FREE PLAY", 700, "LOSE A TURN", 800, 500, 650, 500, 900, "BANKRUPT", 2500, 500, 900, 700, 600, 800, 500, 700, 500, 600, 550, 500, 900]
    return choice(wheel)
def make_text_blank(text):
    l = list(text)
    for i in range(len(text)):
    if text[i].isalpha():
        l[i] = "_"
    return "".join(l)
def fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, letter):
    bt = list(blank_text)
    t = list(text)
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if t[i] == letter:
            bt[i] = letter
    return "".join(bt)
def remove_duplicates(lst):
    result = []
    for i in lst:
        if i not in result:
            result.append(i)
    return result
def vowels_in_text(text):
    result = []
    vowels = ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if text[i] in vowels:
            result.append(text[i])
    result = remove_duplicates(result)
    return result
def wheel_of_fortune():
    print("The category for this puzzle is game show")
    text = "WHEEL OF FORTUNE"
    blank_text = make_text_blank(text)
    print(blank_text)
    print("Player 1 is up first")
    while blank_text != text:
        letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
        vit = vowels_in_text(text)
        player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, 0, 0, 0)
def player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount):
    prize = spin_the_wheel()
    print("The wheel landed on " + str(prize))
    if prize == "BANKRUPT":
        player1amount = 0
        print("We go to player 2 now")
        player2(text, blank_text, vit, 0, player2amount, player3amount)
    elif prize == "LOSE A TURN":
        print("We go to player 2 now")
        player2(text, blank_text, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
    elif prize == "FREE PLAY":
        letter = input("Guess a letter: ").upper()
        if letter not in text:
            letters.remove(letter)
            print("There are no " + letter + "'s")
            print("We go to player 2 now")
            player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
        elif letter not in letters:
            print("That letter's already been called")
            print("We go to player 2 now")
            player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
        else:
            letters.remove(letter)
            if text.count(letter) == 1:
               print("There is 1 " + letter)
               blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, letter)
               print(blank_text)
            player1amount += 500
            choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
            def do(blank_text, choice):
                if choice == "spin the wheel":
                    print("OK, spin the wheel")
                    player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                elif choice == "buy a vowel":
                    vowel = input("OK, buy a vowel: ").upper()
                    if vowel not in text:
                        letters.remove(vowel)
                        print("There are no " + vowel + "'s")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    elif vowel not in letters:
                        print("That vowel's already been called")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    else:
                        letters.remove(vowel)
                        vit.remove(vowel)
                        if text.count(vowel) == 1:
                            print("There is 1 " + vowel)
                            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, vowel)
                            print(blank_text)
                            if vit == []:
                                print("No more vowels")
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice)
                            else:
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice)
                        else:
                            n = text.count(vowel)
                            print("There are " + str(n) + " " + vowel + "'s")
                            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, vowel)
                            print(blank_text)
                            if vit == []:
                                print("No more vowels")
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice)
                            else:
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice)
                elif choice == "solve the puzzle":
                    solution = input("OK, solve the puzzle: ").upper()
                    if solution != text:
                        print("That's not right")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    else:
                        print("That's right")
                        print(text)
                        print("Player 1 amount: $" + str(player1amount))
                        print("Player 2 amount: $" + str(player2amount))
                        print("Player 3 amount: $" + str(player3amount))
            do(blank_text, choice)
        else:
            n = text.count(letter)
            print("There are " + str(n) + " " + letter)
            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, letter)
            print(blank_text)
            p = 500 * n
            player1amount += p
            choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
            def do(blank_text, choice):
                if choice == "spin the wheel":
                    print("OK, spin the wheel")
                    player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                elif choice == "buy a vowel":
                    vowel = input("OK, buy a vowel: ").upper()
                    if vowel not in text:
                        letters.remove(vowel)
                        print("There are no " + vowel + "'s")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    elif vowel not in letters:
                        print("That vowel's already been called")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    else:
                        letters.remove(vowel)
                        vit.remove(vowel)
                        if text.count(vowel) == 1:
                            print("There is 1 " + vowel)
                            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, vowel)
                            print(blank_text)
                            if vit == []:
                                print("No more vowels")
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice)
                            else:
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice)
                        else:
                            n = text.count(vowel)
                            print("There are " + str(n) + " " + vowel + "'s")
                            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, vowel)
                            print(blank_text)
                            if vit == []:
                                print("No more vowels")
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice)
                            else:
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice)
                elif choice == "solve the puzzle":
                    solution = input("OK, solve the puzzle: ").upper()
                    if solution != text:
                        print("That's not right")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    else:
                        print("That's right")
                        print(text)
                        print("Player 1 amount: $" + str(player1amount))
                        print("Player 2 amount: $" + str(player2amount))
                        print("Player 3 amount: $" + str(player3amount))
            do(blank_text, choice)
    else:
        letter = input("Guess a letter: ").upper()
        if letter not in text:
            letters.remove(letter)
            print("There are no " + letter + "'s")
            print("We go to player 2 now")
            player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
        elif letter not in letters:
        print("That letter's already been called")
        print("We go to player 2 now")
        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
    else:
        letters.remove(letter)
        if text.count(letter) == 1:
            print("There is 1 " + letter)
            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, letter)
            print(blank_text)
            player1amount += prize
            choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
            def do(blank_text, choice, player1amount):
                if choice == "spin the wheel":
                    print("OK, spin the wheel")
                    player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                elif choice == "buy a vowel":
                    vowel = input("OK, buy a vowel: ").upper()
                    if vowel not in text:
                        letters.remove(vowel)
                        print("There are no " + vowel + "'s")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    elif vowel not in letters:
                        print("That vowel's already been called")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    else:
                        letters.remove(vowel)
                        vit.remove(vowel)
                        if text.count(vowel) == 1:
                            print("There is 1 " + vowel)
                            player1amount -= 250
                            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, vowel)
                            print(blank_text)
                            if vit == []:
                                print("No more vowels")
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
                            else:
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
                        else:
                            n = text.count(vowel)
                            print("There are " + str(n) + " " + vowel + "'s")
                            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, vowel)
                            print(blank_text)
                            d = 250 * n
                            player1amount -= d
                            if vit == []:
                                print("No more vowels")
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
                            else:
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
                elif choice == "solve the puzzle":
                    solution = input("OK, solve the puzzle: ").upper()
                    if solution != text:
                        print("That's not right")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    else:
                        print("That's right")
                        print(text)
                        print("Player 1 amount: $" + str(player1amount))
                        print("Player 2 amount: $" + str(player2amount))
                        print("Player 3 amount: $" + str(player3amount))
            do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
        else:
            n = text.count(letter)
            print("There are " + str(n) + " " + letter + "'s")
            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, letter)
            print(blank_text)
            p = prize * n
            player1amount += p
            if vit == []:
                choice = input("Would you like to spin the spin the wheel or solve the puzzle?: ")
            else:
                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
            def do(blank_text, choice, player1amount):
                if choice == "spin the wheel":
                    print("OK, spin the wheel")
                    player1(text, blank_text, letters, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                elif choice == "buy a vowel":
                    vowel = input("OK, buy a vowel: ").upper()
                    if vowel not in text:
                        letters.remove(vowel)
                        print("There are no " + vowel + "'s")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    elif vowel not in letters:
                        print("That vowel's already been called")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    else:
                        letters.remove(vowel)
                        vit.remove(vowel)
                        if text.count(vowel) == 1:
                            print("There is 1 " + vowel)
                            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, vowel)
                            print(blank_text)
                            player1amount -= 250
                            if vit == []:
                                print("No more vowels")
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
                            else:
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
                        else:
                            n = text.count(vowel)
                            print("There are " + str(n) + " " + vowel + "'s")
                            blank_text = fill_in_the_blanks(blank_text, text, vowel)
                            print(blank_text)
                            d = 250 * n
                            player1amount -= 250
                            if vit == []:
                                print("No more vowels")
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
                            else:
                                choice = input("Would you like to spin the wheel, buy a vowel, or solve the puzzle?: ")
                                do(blank_text, choice)
                elif choice == "solve the puzzle":
                    solution = input("OK, solve the puzzle: ").upper()
                    if solution != text:
                        print("That's not right")
                        print("We go to player 2 now")
                        player2(text, blank_text, letters, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
                    else:
                        print("That's right")
                        print(text)
                        print("Player 1 amount: $" + str(player1amount))
                        print("Player 2 amount: $" + str(player2amount))
                        print("Player 3 amount: $" + str(player3amount))
            do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
```

And here is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    wheel_of_fortune()
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 41, in wheel_of_fortune
    player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, 0, 0, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 262, in player1
    do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 209, in do
    player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 124, in player1
    do(blank_text, choice)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 74, in do
    player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 262, in player1
    do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 209, in do
    player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 330, in player1
    do(blank_text, choice, player1amount)
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Documents\randompythonprograms\wheeloffortune.py", line 277, in do
    player1(text, blank_text, letters, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)
 TypeError: player1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'player3amount'
```

every time I get this error, I look at the code and I don't see anything that's causing this error, so could somebody help me out here? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you look closely at that last call in the traceback, you'll notice that `vit` is not being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

your function defination is

`def player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount):`

and you are invoking as

`player1(text, blank_text, letters, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)`

it requires 7 parameters, you havent provided the value of `vit`  hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

*your function defination is*

**def player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount):**

*and you are invoking as*

**player1(text, blank_text, letters, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount)**

*it requires 7 parameters, you haven provided the value of 6 hence the error.*

**Solution**

**def player1(text, blank_text, letters, vit, player1amount, player2amount, player3amount):**